# How does iframe behave in HTML5 without the sandbox attribute?

Tags: html, iframe

What is the behaviour of `<iframe>` in HTML5 when the `sandbox` attribute is not present? Is it same as `sandbox=""`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's more like the opposite.

When you add the `sandbox` attribute, you create the sandbox : you force the content to be much more restricted. This protects your user from the content of the iframe, which isn't the case without the attribute, especially when the content is served from the same origin.

Adding elements in the `sandbox` list reduces the restrictions. That's why they're called `"allow-something"`.

Here's [the W3.org reference](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/#attr-iframe-sandbox).

And here's an almost-clear introduction from MS: [How to Safeguard your Site with HTML5 Sandbox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/hh563496.aspx)

Comment: but then same origin is also allowed without Sandbox but NOT different origin. This means some part of sandbox is there without sandbox attribute. I wished to know all those in a way listed in allow-*

Comment: Last I checked Chrome did the opposite though, it treated missing sandbox attribute as `sandbox=""` so most of our site broke

Comment: ChatGPD: "This bug occurred in Chrome versions 45 to 63 (inclusive) and was fixed in later versions."